# Duda sobre como obtener valor $_GET en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Requiero obtener un valor pero que este solo sea por metodo `$_GET` ya que lo uso en URL tipo `www.foo.com/?tab=bar`

Y en el PHP requiero saber si entro ese parámetro en PHP nativo lo haría

```
$tab = $_GET['tab'];
```

Pero en Laravel uso

```
$tab = $request->input('tab');
```

Pero con ello no puedo controlar que sea solo por método `$_GET` o al menos no se como.

Esta la opción de usar `$request->isMethod()` pero tengo la necesidad de usar el método `$_POST` junto con el `$_GET` debido a que el `$_GET` lo uso para indicar la tab que quiero editar. Ya que esta funcionalidad la requiero para una parte de mi sitio donde edito una publicación pero tiene diversas tabs.

Si uso `$_GET` para detectar la tab podría ser

```
if ($request->isMethod('get') && $request->input('tab') == 'photos') {
    /* Edito la tab de Fotos */
} else {
    /* Tab default */
}
```

Pero si requiero capturar el momento cuando se hace submit

```
if ($request->isMethod('post') && $request->input('tab') == 'photos') {
    /* Submit Edito la tab de Fotos */
} else {
    /* Tab default */
}
```

El problema es que `$request->input('tab')` podría ser por `$_GET` o  `$_POST` por eso requiero algo que me indique que tome el valor solo por `$_GET`

Nota: Estoy en Laravel 7

Comment: Muéstranos el método que tienes en tu controlador en donde quieres capturar ese valor

Comment: Puedo usar `$request->input()` pero necesito que el valor sea exclusivo por método `$_GET` así como en PHP nativo

Comment: Lo edite, no se si me explique ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de evaluar el verbo HTTP  que recibimos por el objeto `$request` es usar el método [`isMethod()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#request-path-and-method) dentro de un condicional para evaluar  si el verbo HTTP corresponde al string pasado como argumento y establecer acciones en concecuencia así:

```
if ($request->isMethod('get') {
    /*Acciones si es get*/
} else {
    /*Aquí si no es get */
}
```

Comment: Pense en eso, pero el problema es que igual uso ese `$_GET` cuando se hace `$_POST` ya que es una parte de mi sitio web donde se edita, entonces puedes editar una tab u otra

Comment: Por eso requiero algo similar al `$_GET` nativo donde obtengo el valor, pero solo por medio del metodo `$_GET`

Comment: No comprendo el impedimento con la solución si está misma evaluará si el verbo del objeto es get o post, pero igual te recomiendo revises la otra opción que es el método `method`

Comment: Agregue algo a mi publicación

Comment: Ya encontre la respuesta, mira https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/php/en-laravel-como-puedo-obtener-solo-post-parametros/1050564491/ a esto me refería

Comment: Publicala si gustas como respuesta